# what is the difference between window size and context length of language model?

Tags: nlp, training, gpt, pretraining, chatgpt

is window size and context length of language model one and the same thing?

******** following text is added as question with ONLY above text was not allowed *****
I am trying to understand how GPT model is trained and this question to my mind.
I tried to search answer on google but couldn't find an answer thus asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in large language models, window and context length refer to the same thing: the maximum token sequence length that the language model can handle at once.